# Nethereum when sending transaction to contract Number was less than the array's lower bound in the first dimension. (Parameter 'destinationIndex')

Tags: tokens, nethereum

Hello i have problem with simply smartcontract:

```
   [Function("saveData")]
   public class SmartContractDataFunc : FunctionMessage
   {
       [Parameter("uint256","_id", 1)]
       public UInt64 Id { get; set; }
       [Parameter("string", "_data", 2)]
       public string Data { get; set; }
       [Parameter("string", "_projectName", 3)]
       public string ProjectName { get; set; }
   }
```

```
    function saveData(uint256 _id, string memory _data, string memory _projectName) public onlyAdmin {
        dataRecords[_id] = DataRecord(_id, _data, _projectName);
    }
```

and calling:

```
    public async Task<TransactionReceipt> SaveDataAsync(SmartContractData dataRecord)
    {
        var handler = _web3.Eth.GetContractTransactionHandler<SmartContractDataFunc>();
        var message = new SmartContractDataFunc()
        {
            Id = ulong.Parse(dataRecord.Id.ToString()),
            Data = dataRecord.Data,
            ProjectName = dataRecord.ProjectName,
            AmountToSend = new HexBigInteger(0),
            GasPrice = new HexBigInteger(await _web3.Eth.GasPrice.SendRequestAsync()),
            //Gas = Nethereum.Web3.Web3.Convert.ToWei(new BigDecimal(0.00099), UnitConversion.EthUnit.Ether),
            FromAddress = _sender,
            Nonce = new HexBigInteger(await _web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(_sender)).Value + 1
        };
        var estimation = await handler.EstimateGasAsync(_contractAddress, message);
        message.Gas = estimation != null ? estimation.Value : new HexBigInteger(1000000);

        var x = await handler.SendRequestAndWaitForReceiptAsync(_contractAddress, message);
        return x;
    }
```

Nethereum Version `Web3: v4.18, Autogen.ContractAbi: v4.11`

I always receive error from title and `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll`

I managed this object with a lot of tries of changing parameters but it also not works. I also checked it on another contract, admin address, and it gives same result